# Backbone - iterating over objects in an array attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, backbone.js, reference, get

I have a model with two arrays, bright and normal. Each array includes objects which are representing colors. I want to implement in model a method allowing to set some properties (for example hue) of this colors. So I wrote this:

```
setHue: function(hue) {
    _.each([this.get('brigth'), this.get('normal')], function(colors) {
        _.each(colors, function(color) {
            color.setHue(hue + this.getHue());
        });
    });
},
```

I think it's clear - I try to iterate over every color in both `bright` and `normal` arrays. And it doesn't update colors inside these arrays. This color inside `_.each` seems to have a new value, but it looks it's only a copy of color, not a reference. Do anyone know how to do what I want? I mean with `_.each` loop, I don't wanna mess up with `for`, `length` and indexes.

Comment: YES! Thank you! "The darkest place is under the candlestick". `normal` was loging me proper values inside a loop, and I was checking `bright` after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bright is misspelled. You entered brigth.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I think you have a general problem here. Let's try with an example:

```
this.get('brigth')
```

will return an array, not a model, correct?

If so,

```
_.each([this.get('brigth'), this.get('normal')], function(colors) { ...
```

will loop over an array of arrays, i.e. colors will get an array, not a model nor a collection. Consequently, color will be a item of an array (I assume a string). Thus color with not have a method setHue.

Additionally, Paul is right as well
    this.getHue()
this does not refer to a model, since you are switching context twice (once for each each-Loop). 
I hope I did not get it totally wrong here.